# Как сделать сортировку после применения normalizr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

На стеке react/redux есть запрос к api. Приходит примерно такие данные:

```
  [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
  ]
```

Массив с объектами, внутри объектов есть ещё поля с массивами объектов. С помощью normalizr, делаю нормализацию и получаю `result` и `entities` объекты. Поля из `entities` сохраняются в `store`. Затем стоит задача отсортировать по какому нибудь полю объект, но normalizr превращает массив в объект и становиться затруднительно его сортировать. Вопрос как сделать это правильно?

Мои варианты:

1. Делать сортировку до применения normalizr. Минус в том что тогда в store придется записывать данные не нормализованные, а то что с сервера пришло, или где-то на этапе после прихода данных с сервера дергать store, брать от туда по какому полю нужно сортировать, проводить сортировку и нормализовать его после этого.
2. После нормализации создать ещё один массив, в котором будут объекты с id и полями по которым можно отсортировать. Проводить сортировку на нем, потом перебирать его и подставлять id. Например: `entities.users[id]`. Минус в том что normalizr уже создает массив для перебора id `result`. Придется либо изменять его либо новый делать.

Если есть у кого-то опыт такой или идеи подскажите.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сортировать не сами данные а как раз массив id

Подробнее ответ на ваш вопрос дал [Дэн Абрамов](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/9)

> The sort order is retained in the ID lists. It's just that entities
>   themselves are extracted into maps.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что речь о варианте с отсортированным массивом id? Если да, добавь это в ответ, а если нет, то это не ответ, а комментарий.